# Server having two IP

Tags: window

I have a doubt. I logged in remote server with IP Address say A. After login host name and IP in desktop shows different IP Address say B. How Two different IP address showing in same session. Remote IP  and system IP are different.

If any one have idea about this kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, can you post the output of `ipconfig` here? (or, `ifconfig` for Unix like platforms)

It's certainly possible that a machine can have multiple IP addresses. One possibility is that you are seeing the private IP address ("system IP" in your question) after logging in and then the public IP address ("remote IP" that you are referring to) using which you logged in to the remote server.

And, another possibility is that the server can has multiple interfaces / NIC cards and each NIC has an IP address associated with it.

This can be confirmed from the output of `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`.